# Generate several array with different condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, grep

There is an array named `dataArray` which I need to separate with a different condition. I use the `grep` to generate a new one named `colorGroup1`.

```
var colorGroup1 = $.grep(dataArray, function(item,key){
    var vote_percentage = parseInt(item.vote_percentage);
    var result = vote_percentage>=0 && vote_percentage <25;
    return result;
});
```

but I have lots of `colorGroup` with a different condition. If I use grep, I need to operate many times. Like this↓

```
var colorGroup2 = $.grep(dataArray, function(item,key){
    var vote_percentage = parseInt(item.vote_percentage);
    var result = vote_percentage>=25 && vote_percentage <50;
    return result;
});
var colorGroup3 = $.grep(dataArray, function(item,key){
    var vote_percentage = parseInt(item.vote_percentage);
    var result = vote_percentage>=50 && vote_percentage <75;
    return result;
});

//.......and so on.......
```

Are there any methods to generate several arrays only do it once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `$.grep`, you might use the built-in `.reduce` to sort the items in the input array into the sections you need. For example:

```
const colorGroups = dataArray.reduce((a, item) => {
  const groupIndex = Math.floor(item.vote_percentage / 25);
  a[groupIndex].push(item);
  return a;
}, [[], [], [], []]);
```

Then `colorGroups` will be an array of the `colorGroups`. (for example, `colorGroups[0]` will be equivalent to your original variable named `colorGroup1`).

A single array (or object) containing each `colorGroup` is probably more appropriate than having multiple standalone variables, but if you do want standalone variables, you can destructure the result:

```
const [colorGroup1, colorGroup2, colorGroup3, colorGroup4] =
dataArray.reduce((a, item) => {
  const groupIndex = Math.floor(item.vote_percentage / 25);
  a[groupIndex].push(item);
  return a;
}, [[], [], [], []]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$.each` with your `dataArray` as follows:

```
var colorGroup1 = [];
var colorGroup2 = [];
var colorGroup3 = [];
$.each(dataArray, function( index, value ) {
   var vote_percentage = parseInt(value.vote_percentage);
   if(vote_percentage>=0 && vote_percentage <25)
       colorGroup1.push(value);
   if(vote_percentage>=25 && vote_percentage <50)
       colorGroup2.push(value);
   if(vote_percentage>=50 && vote_percentage <75)
       colorGroup3.push(value);
});
```